# OpenMPI Send and Receive Data Types When Not Passing Data

Tags: openmpi

If I'm only using a process receive (followed by a subsequent send at some point) and I don't need to transfer any data, what is the *proper* syntax for the call in the context of the data type?

Currently, I'm doing something like:

```
MPI_Recv (NULL, 0, MPI_INT, my_id, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
```

Is there some ignored value we can pass in that is analogous to `MPI_STATUS_IGNORE`, but for the data type (argument 3)?  Or is what I'm doing okay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it right !

FWIW the MPI standard does **not** currently allows using `MPI_DATATYPE_NULL` here.

Comment: Thank you, so it doesn’t matter what data type we pass in if we aren’t sending any data?

Comment: Yes, any valid datatype with a zero count can be used here. And just for the sake of being pedantic, you can also create and use a derived datatype with a zero size, and use any non negative count (which would be unnecessarily convoluted imho)